# in Android how to query which package should be selected?

Tags: android

I have an application where an activity pops up before the login screen with a spinner and one button. In the spinner it gives me two options. Both being from the same project but different verisons. for example one version uses the internet and the other doesn't. So my question is how can i query which package to select in my first activty of the application? Let's say that i have two packages in my project. Each one containing a different version of the project.

Answer (score 0):

use activity specific intent to direct your user to desired package. for example:

Activity1 is from package A, and Activity2 is from package B, then make selection as:

```
if(goToFirstPackage){
     startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Activity1));
}
else
     startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Activity2));
```